# Test dynamic import components in jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

Based on a condition I dynamically imported a component and assigned it to an object property. After that, I rendered it in the template using vue `<component :is="">`.
Everything is working as expected from the components level. But unable to cover the test cases in jest. I see `[Function anonymous]` in the console

Function:

```
export default function useCharts() {
    const {isValid} = storeToRefs(useValidInfo());
    const charts = computed(() => [
        {
          id: 'themes',
          component: isValid.value ? async () => import('./path/component1') : null,
          grow: '0',
          title: 'component1',
        }
      ]);
    return {
        charts
    }
}
```

testcase:

```
jest.mock('./path/component1', () => 'component1');
describe('useCharts', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        setActivePinia(createPinia());
    });
    it('should return charts', () => {
        const store = useValidInfo();
        store.setIsValid(true);
        const {charts} = useCharts();
        expect(charts.value).toEqual([
            {
              id: 'themes',
              component: component1, // this is the mock, i see [Function anonymous]
              grow: '0',
              title: 'component1',
            }
        ]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a dynamic import function we can assign the value to a variable, call the function, and check whether it is defined or not. In this way, the jest is parsing through the line of code.

```
const {charts} = useCharts();
const chart= charts.value[0].component as any;
const promise = chart();
expect(promise).toBeDefined();
```